# Float não funciona de maneira correta

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com um probleminha para me achar usando a propriedade float do css. Atualmente é isso que possuo com meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que além de torto e fora da caixa azul quando redimensiono a tela bagunça muito. Onde estou errando? Segue meus códigos html e css:

```css
#section-one{
  background-image: url(../images/barra-sessao1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.conteudo-1{
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.conteudo-1 h1{
  color: #d58502;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.conteudo-1 p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#imagem-direita{
  float: right; 
}


#imagem-direita img{
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Section one -->
<section id="section-one">

  <div id="imagem-direita">
    <img src="images/bg-conteudo.png" alt="devdream" >
  </div> 

  <div class="conteudo-1">
    <h1>devdream</h1>
    <p>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur
    </p> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Antes de mais nada, por que está usando `float` nesse layout afinal de contas? Acho que o problema maior é esse. Independente disso, tenho a impressão de que você não está usando `position:` em nenhum elemento, o que já é problemático também.

Comment: estou usando float porque a imagem deve flutuar do lado do texto mais nao queria que sai-se da box que seria essa imagem com efeito skew mais o maior problema e quando redimenciono

Comment: Eu acho que compensa usar right: com posição absoluta, mas teria que ver o código melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa notar que a maioria dos layouts apresenta uma "área útil" que na maioria das vezes é de 960  a 1000 px. Envolva seu código numa div container, seta uma largura max e atribua um margin: 0 auto para centraliza-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o bootstrap para regulamentar as questões de dimensões, que neste caso, você usando um `<div class="container">`, todo conteúdo ficaria dentro da div correta... Basta dar uma estudada na documentação: http://getbootstrap.com.br/getting-started/